# Is a copy-pasted Google Docs URL the same as the "Share Link" option?

Tags: google-docs

I want to cut out a step from the process I'm following. I need to copy/paste several Google Docs URLs, and it’s easier to grab them from the URL bar on top of the browser than to press “share” and then “copy link”. The URL ends in “edit”, while the copy link URL ends in “sharing”. Is there any real difference between these two URLs?

Comment: This blog post on Joomlatools explains the Google Docs URL modifiers: https://www.joomlatools.com/blog/extensions/google-drive-url-modifiers#google-drive-url-modifiers

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please take the [Tour] and review [ask]. Then [edit] the question to share what you've tried to solve this and why that didn't address your needs.